# Best approach for using azure service bus with azure function for ERP order import

Tags: azure, azure-functions, azureservicebus, azure-servicebus-queues

---

I’m in need of some second opinions and guidance on how to use Azure Functions in combination with Azure Service Bus in the scenario described below. Coding is not an issue its about selecting the most appropriate method. Sadly, I have not found any good example of this online so now I’m reaching out for some help.

### Scenario

I have an ecommerce customer that is sending a few thousand orders a day to an ERP system. The normal day operations are not an issue, but we would like to make the solution more robust to handle for example “Black Friday” surges. Currently the website can hold x amount of orders before that database is full and is forced to close or send order downstream. Currently the website sends order directly into the ERP system and it is this part I want to decouple with Azure Server Bus Queues. With this decoupling we can continue pushing new orders to the queue and consuming these at our own pace in the ERP without flooding any system.

### My thoughts about how to set this up

1. The website can send messages directly to the Service Bus Queue. An Azure Function is bound to trigger on every new message in the queue and will send that message to the ERP system.
2. Same as above however the website first sends a message to an Azure Function that puts it into the queue.
3. The website sends messages to the queue like in point 1 or 2. Instead of binding a function to the queue we setup a scheduled function. The function will run frequently and send 1 message to the ERP system per run.
4. The website sends messages to the queue like in point 1 or 2. Here we do not send messages to the ERP system but instead the ERP system is the one who reads the queue. Do not like this approach but its possible to do and easy to administrate by ERP users.

### Questions

- If I go with point 1 or 2 above should the function responsible for delivering the message to the ERP system send 1 or multiple orders per trigger?
- If I go with point 1 or 2 it should still be possible to flood the ERP system since they most likely trigger at the same time they get put in?
- If the ERP system is down and the queue grows, do I need a separate scheduled function to handle the queue until it is empty?

We do not have to discuss the dead letter queue here, that is another topic.

How would you approach this or if you have done a similar solution what method did you use?

Thank you for your guidance much appriciated!

Answer (score 0):

We've learned a lot in the past couple of years working with Azure Functions and Service Bus to solve similar scenarios you mentioned above. You're definitely on the right track regards to wanting to decouple in case of a surge. To give you some peace of mind with your choice to use Azure Service Bus, we normally push hundreds of events a minute through our topics and subscriptions and it holds up pretty well.

Let me just share some of the lessons we learned:

1. The concurrent number of incoming requests within the same second
   was one of our breaking points. The website when written properly
   will easily accommodate multiple incoming requests but we learned
   about "port exhaustion" related to outbound web requests to our
   Azure Function. Review the scope and lifetime of your web client and
   the limits of your app service plan / web server.
2. If you choose to use a consumption plan for your Azure Function, be
   aware that it sometimes takes a long time to start. Whatever is
   hitting the function will have to implement retries (probably a good
   practice anyway).
3. A Service Bus Message has a size limit (which can be increased, but
   there's still a limit). We randomly hit it with one of our payloads
   that contains a bulk of information. Know the worst case scenario
   payload size you may encounter.
4. In the event something goes wrong and there are tens of thousands of
   messages in the queue, there is no easy way to query what's in
   there. Make sure you're fine with that otherwise consider
   doing fast writes into a database that can be queried.
5. The Azure Function can be triggered by Service Bus and can spawn
   multiple concurrent executions of the code (which is desired) and
   with a limit. Be aware of any limitations with code to update your
   ERP. You will have no control over Service Bus triggers.
6. Be conscious about the function's storage account, functions with
   same name will have their trigger settings and locks stepping on
   each other (dev vs. prod environment).
7. Connections to Azure Service Bus will sometimes fail, just the
   nature of services hosted in the cloud. It only happens a few times
   and recovers after a few seconds.

**Consider doing this:**

**Website** -> **Azure API Management Gateway** -> **Azure Function A** -> **Service Bus** -> **Azure Function B** -> **ERP**

1. Azure API Management with AppInsights enabled is a nice extra layer allowing you to secure, monitor, and route to your Function A. In cases where you need to route incoming requests to some emergency bucket it's a life saver.
2. Consider allowing function 1 to accept an array of your items. Enable AppInsights, add code for telemetry, providing preview of throughput in terms of orders.
3. Function B with a configurable timer trigger and some app configuration for number of messages to process from the queue. Allows you to throttle flow of data to your ERP. This may be debatable as you won't be able to scale this function out with multiple instances, but I'm assuming the original concern was to control the pace. Also enable same AppInsights, telemetry, logging, etc.

I'm hoping I don't draw too much criticism from this. We learned the hard way and eventually received some really good guidance from Azure architects and engineers later.